# In ruby, how can I check for social security number that doesn't start with 9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I need to validate social security number using require expression or ruby way so that the first number doesn't start with 9. Any suggestions? This is as far as I have:`/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/`

Comment: Can you provide some of the surrounding code for context? If you're not getting any of the given solutions to work, then perhaps there's something else wrong other than the regex itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basic. I recommend that you follow a tutorial on regular expressions. Simply change the first digit to 0-8:

```
/^[0-8]\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/
```

Here is [the expression in Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/RUm7b3PUxW).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've tried that before and it didn't work.

Comment: @NicholasAlek define “doesn’t work”, i.e., what is a test case for which it fails?

Answer (score 1):

Add a negative lookahead

```
/\A(?!9)\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\z/
```

Comment: I am confused which one to use, this one or one in accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING!** Untested regex follows:

`/^[0-8][0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/`

Comment: If you haven't tested it, don't post it. You can test ruby regex at http://rubular.com

Answer (score 0):

Validates SS numbers with or without dashes that doesn't start with `9`

```
if subject =~ /\A(?:^(?!9)\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$|^(?!9)\d{9}$)\Z/
    # Successful match
else
    # Match attempt failed
end
```

<kbd>[REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/e8cgPwvoPJ)</kbd>

***REGEX EXPLANATION:***

```
Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «^(?!9)\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$»
   Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
   Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!9)»
      Match the character “9” literally «9»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{3}»
      Exactly 3 times «{3}»
   Match the character “-” literally «-»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
   Match the character “-” literally «-»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{4}»
      Exactly 4 times «{4}»
   Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match) «^(?!9)\d{9}$»
   Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
   Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!9)»
      Match the character “9” literally «9»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{9}»
      Exactly 9 times «{9}»
   Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
```